Intersection complex and push forward of constant sheaf
Let X be a variety with $\pi: Y 
\rightarrow  X $ being a resolution of singularity map. By decomposition theorem we have, $\pi_{*} Q_{Y} =\bigoplus \; ^{p}\mathcal{H}^{i}(\pi_{*} Q_{Y})$ where  $\;^{p}\mathcal{H}^{i}$ is the perverse cohomology. This decomposition further breaks down into simple pieces $IC(X_{i}, L_{i})$ where $L_{i}$ is a local system on locally closed subvariety $X_{i}$ of $X$.
My question is why $IC(X)$ appears in the refined decomposition?
I know that map $\pi$ is isomorphism on the smooth locus $j:U \rightarrow X $ such that $j^{*} \pi_{*}Q_{Y}= Q_{U}$. How to use this fact to conclude $IC(X)$ is summand of $\pi_{*}Q_{Y}$?
